# Can you alias a basic type like String in GraphQL? like `type Token = String`?

Tags: graphql, apollo, typegraphql

Can you alias a basic type like String in GraphQL? like `type Token = String`?

Or it *has* to be a class/struct?

Comment: just define a scalar?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only about name, just leave is as string.

If it's a special kind of string, like Mongo ObjectID, which has rules like string length or checksum, you can create GraphQL scalar for that purpose.